# Acts-as-Taggable-On showing hash object instead of tag names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

Acts-as-Taggable-on is failing to correctly print out only the name column, and not the entire hash of information on the object itself. How can I setup the show page to print out each tag separately for the model? The code that I have so far is below.

show.html.erb

```
<%= @user.user_profile.tags.each do |tag| %>
<%= tag.name %>
<% end %>
```

results shown on show page

```
#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x2b7534d0> games [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "games", created_at: "2017-08-25 15:54:30", updated_at: "2017-08-25 15:54:30", taggings_count: 1>] 1
```

console output

```
 Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  UserProfile Load (8.0ms)  SELECT  "user_profiles".* FROM "user_profiles" WHERE "user_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (15.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."context" = $3  [["taggable_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "UserProfile"], ["context", "tags"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2  [["taggable_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "UserProfile"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (25.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "UserProfile"]]
```

user_profile.rb

```
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :abilities
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<% @user.user_profile.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.name %>
<% end %>
```

(without '=' after the '<%' in the first line)

Comment: I must be tired lol. Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to do.